# Find $\ker f$ where $f(a+bx+cx^2) = (2(a-c),a-b,c-a)$ and state whether it is injective

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find $\ker f$ where $f(a+bx+cx^2) = (2(a-c),a-b,c-a)$ and state
>   whether it is injective.

I did:

$$\ker f = \{ (a+bx+cx^2) \in \mathbb{R}_2[x]:f(a+bx+cx^2)=(0,0,0)\} \\
= \{(a+bx+cx^2\in\mathbb{R}_2[x]: (2(a-c),a-b,c-a)=(0,0,0)\} \\
=(...) = \\
=\{(a+bx+cx^2)\in\mathbb{R}_2[x]:a=b=c\} = \\
= \{(a+ax+ax^2):a \in \mathbb{R}\} = \\
\langle(1+x+x^2)\rangle$$

For it to be injective, $\ker f = 0_v$. The kernel isn't equal to the zero vector, so it isn't injective. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Yes, you have done it correctly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That was fast! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel is the set of polynomials for which $a=b=c$. You are correct this is not just the zero polynomial, hence it is not injective.